# How can I make days wrap around in a QDateEdit?

Tags: qt, pyqt

The standard behaviour is, that as soon as the day reaches 31 the step-up button stops working. I'd like it to reset to 1 and jump to the next month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not had the opportunity to test this, but I know that QDateEdit implements QAbstractSpinBox, so you should be able to call

```
myDateEdit.setWrapping(True)
```

which should accomplish what you want.

[Doc Link](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qabstractspinbox.html#wrapping-prop)

Update:

The term for this behaviour is apparently called "rollover" and here is one person's implementation, which (again, I haven't tested it) appears to be another potential solution:

[Rollover QDateEdit](http://www.qtcentre.org/forum/f-qt-programming-2/t-qdateedit-monthday-rollover-11139-post59196.html#post59196)

He makes the point that his implementation doesn't consider min or max dates though.

Comment: Works only partially. As soon as the day field reaches 32, it jumps back to 1. But it still doesn't increase the month count.

Comment: If that's the case, then you may have to re-implement stepBy/stepUp/stepDown in QDateTimeEdit, which if you've ever seen the source code for that is not very trivial. I'm working on this widget today coincidentally so I'll update if something comes to mind